# How to change a character in runtime, C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In the properties section I changed the passwordChar, but i want to change the passwordChar to nothing.

Something like this:

```
private void passwordG_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    passwordG.PasswordChar = none;
}
```

Comment: OP means nothing i think @ElectricRouge

Comment: i cant just wrtie "nathing"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you mean you want to change it back to nothing. then we have char `\0`

```
private void passwordG_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    passwordG.PasswordChar = '\0';
}
```

[set char to null or the equivalent of zero](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/cf8fba17-4974-4c12-8743-f5636c9763d4/set-char-to-null-or-the-equivalent-of-zero)